# Error with tabbed app in xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have tableview in firstcontroller with

items = [1, 2, 3, 4]

(items is loaded from Firebase)

In secondController I add new item 5 to Firebase

When I back to FirstController, my items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

How can i fix it?

Comment: You forgot to clear your array, can you show the code that you are trying.

Comment: Let me guess... you called FireBase in `viewDidLoad` of the first controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to empty your `items` array in `viewDidAppear`of your FirstViewController. See if this helps.